# Git `pre-commit hooks` how to refer from parent directory instead of direct folder

Tags: git, githooks

My `.husky` placed in the parent directory. in the child I have the `nx workspace` code. in this case how can I add the reference link to check my script in the parent directory?

```
    parent/
├─ nx-workspace/
│  ├─ package.json
│  ├─ apps
│  ├─ libs
.git
.husky
```

here the package.json scripts should read the git and husky details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `pre-commit` hook, we can get the absolute path to the .git directory by

```
git rev-parse --absolute-git-dir
```

And then it's easy to get the path to other directories if we know the folder structure.